# visual flow - how to get existing field values of record and fill it on flow screen fields

Tags: visual-workflow, visual-flows

working on visual flow and created one flow for insert and working fine. again added one flow for update the records and that also working fine but the problem i am facing is that at time of updating i want to fill the fields with existing values of that record. i can get the id of that field but how to fill the other field values on that flow screen. following is how i created flow and what it displays on screen.

[image]

[image]

in 2nd image i can get the id which highlighted in address bar. but want to get the type value and auto select that type on type dropdown on second screen.

any help..??

Comment: I typically pass the record Id to the flow and in my first element, do a fast lookup to store any fields from the record that I need to use in a sObject variable.. Alternatively you can pass all the values to the flow through the URL. I prefer the former.  Then You can set default values for your flow screen fields to the relevant sObject variable fields

Comment: this really helped me to understand how to get the values.. now the problem is that i can get the values from that record, for this i created one sobject variable and in default value i selected that sobjectvariable.field_name, now this works when i take text box, i means i can get existing record filed values in text box but i cant assign default value to dropdown. anything i am doing wrong for this here?

Comment: hey sorry i missed your response.  you definitely can assign default value to dropdown.  you need to create a choice element, and you can assign a value to that. i will try to add an answer this week w more details.  see: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.salesforce_vpm_guide.meta/salesforce_vpm_guide/vpm_designer_choice_options.htm